# why row not 100 % of width when I make dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

can you please tell why row not taking 100% width.I follow the following steps.
press "add case button" .it will generate a row.select "add case" option and press add it will generate inside row.But it width is not 100%.

```
function addNewCaseInside(id){
    //add new inside collapsible inside collapsible row.

    alert($("#list" +id));
    $('#'+id).append('<ul><li >' +
            '<div data-role="collapsible">' +
            '<h3>nnnn</h3>' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li>' +
            '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="Smoker">' +
            '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="TestCase" checked="checked">' +
            '<label for="radio-choice-1">Add Test Case</label>' +
            '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="TestCommand">' +
            '<label for="radio-choice-2">Add Test Command</label>' +
            '</fieldset>' +
            '<a  data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" class="addClickClass">Add</a>' +
        '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</li><ul>')
            $('#'+id).trigger('create');





}
```

Comment: When debugging, you shouldn't use `alert()`. Use the console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset styles if you test in in fiddle. By default browser applies styles to UL elements (in this case padding-left). So if you include reset styles into your fiddle it will work as expected.

Of course you can fix it simple like this without notmalize.css:

```
.ui-collapsible-content ul {padding: 0;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/22/

Also note that you might not need reset.css for actual mobile devices as its browser can have different user agent default stylesheet without such unwanted behavior.